# Issue with chained callbacks not executing in Plotly Dash app

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I'm currently learning about chained callbacks in Dash but am stalling. Would someone with more experience be able to review the code provided and identify any mistakes I might have made?

My goal is to chain callbacks such that the output from one callback (which uses the `long_lasting_query()` function) serves as the input to another callback. However, it appears that none of the callbacks are being executed.

```py
import argparse

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
from dash import Dash, Input, Output, State, dcc, html
from dash.dash_table import DataTable


def parse_args() -> argparse.Namespace:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Dash example",
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
    )

    parser.add_argument(
        "-a",
        "--addr",
        type=str,
        metavar="arg",
        required=True,
        help="address to bind to (ip:port)",
    )
    parser.add_argument("--debug", action="store_true", help="run in debug mode")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    return args


def long_lasting_query() -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder_unfiltered.csv"
    )

    return df


columns = ["country", "continent", "year", "lifeExp", "pop", "gdpPercap"]

app = Dash(
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP], suppress_callback_exceptions=True
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.P(
            "Year: ",
            style={"display": "inline-block", "margin-right": "8px"},
        ),
        dcc.Input(id="year", type="number", min=0),
        html.Button("Submit", id="submit-val", n_clicks=0),
        DataTable(
            columns=[{"name": c, "id": c} for c in columns],
            id="tbl",
            page_size=20,
            sort_action="native",
            style_header={
                "textAlign": "center",
            },
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("db_data", "value"),
    Input("submit-val", "n_clicks"),
    State("year", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def load_data(n_clicks, value):
    df = long_lasting_query()
    df = df[df["year"] == value]
    if df.empty:
        return "{}"

    return df.to_json(orient="split")


@app.callback(
    Output("tbl", "data"),
    Input("db_data", "value"),
)
def update_table(value):
    df = pd.read_json(value, orient="split")
    if df.empty:
        return "{}"

    return df.to_dict("records")


def main() -> None:
    args = parse_args()
    host, port = args.addr.split(":")
    app.run(host=host, port=port, debug=args.debug)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I expect to obtain data that has been filtered based on the specified year.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update an output with the ID `db_data`, but you don't have an element with that ID in your Dash `app.layout`. For transferring data between callbacks, you can use `dcc.Store`, as demonstrated below.

The following code,

```py
import dash
from dash import Input, Output, State
from dash import dcc, html

import dash.dash_table as dt

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

import pandas as pd


def long_lasting_query() -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_csv(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminder_unfiltered.csv"
    )
    return df


columns = ["country", "continent", "year", "lifeExp", "pop", "gdpPercap"]

app = dash.Dash(
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
    suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
)

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        html.P(
            "Year: ",
            style={"display": "inline-block", "margin-right": "8px"},
        ),
        dcc.Input(id="year", type="number", min=0),
        html.Button("Submit", id="submit-val", n_clicks=0),
        dt.DataTable(
            columns=[{"name": c, "id": c} for c in columns],
            id="tbl",
            page_size=20,
            sort_action="native",
            style_header={"textAlign": "center",},
        ),
        dcc.Store(id="db_data"),
    ],
    style={"margin": "10%"},
)


@app.callback(
    Output("db_data", "data"),
    Input("submit-val", "n_clicks"),
    State("year", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def load_data(n_clicks, value):
    if not value:
        return {}
    df = long_lasting_query()
    df = df[df["year"] == value]
    return df.to_dict("records")


@app.callback(
    Output("tbl", "data"), Input("db_data", "data"),
)
def update_table(data):
    if not data:
        return []
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df.to_dict("records")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

produces this app functionality:
[image: Screen shot recording of dash app demo]

When the "Submit" button is clicked, the first callback will execute the `long_lasting_query()`, filter the dataframe based on the given year, and store the result in `db_data`. The second callback will then take this stored data, convert it back to a dataframe, and update the `tbl` DataTable with the filtered results.